# Non-clickable Context Menu Header

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

When creating a context menu, is there a way to have header text included? For example, when a user clicks a button, I want a context menu to show with two options. There should also be text above the options, with a sentence such as: 'Please select an option'.

Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't find your question at first. [Had to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527295/how-to-create-a-non-selectable-context-menu-item)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't do it with the designer but you can do it in code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(0, new ToolStripLabel("Please select an option"));
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(1, new ToolStripSeparator());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hans.  It was programmatically that I was looking for.  I'll use this now.

Comment: You may like to bold the text too like so:
`contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(0, new ToolStripLabel("Please select an option") { Font = new Font(DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold) });`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a menu with 4 elements in this order:

- "Please select an option"   -Disabled (this make it gray out and unlickable)
- Separator (------)
- Option1  -Enabled
- Option2  -Enabled

Comment: In addition to making it disabled, mess around with it's colors to give it the proper look (if that matters to you)