# How to create a non-selectable context menu item?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, contextmenu

I have a simple context menu. And I would like to add a **title item** to it, which cannot be selected, not even highlighted with the mouse cursor. When I set `Enabled = false;` I still can mark it and it feels stupid because it's obviously disabled and the text is gray.

---

**Example:**

Like this. I can't mark or select the "Menu" item. It must never be blue. So I want this in my C# application. Simple, no styles.

[image]

---

**Test code:**

```
public Form1()
{
    ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
    ContextMenuStrip.Font = new Font("Arial", 8);
    ToolStripItem a = ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("--- Title ---");
    a.Enabled = false;
    a.Font = new Font("Consolas", 16, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
    ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Alice");
    ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Bob");
    ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Conrad");
}
```

Comment: It's probably too late for you now, but I would recommend ditching winforms and use WPF where you would have complete control over things like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to add a `ToolStripLabel` item to your strip, like this:

```
ContextMenuStrip.Items.Insert(0, new ToolStripLabel("--- Title ---"));
```

This should add a label which serves as a marker, and should not show anything when the mouse moves over it.

(There's a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595440/2609288), which covers the same point.)

Comment: That's nice. I just can't stylize it with BackColor :(